# Difficulty with writing short RPG Script

Tags: python

Write a function named "compute_xp" that takes two parameters which are an integer and boolean in that order. The function will return the 44993 if the boolean is false (lost the battle) or 44993 plus the integer parameter if the boolean is true (won the battle)

```
def compute_xp(i, b):
    if b == 44993:
        return 44993 
    else:
        return 44993 + i
```

This is my code, but I keep getting an incorrect answer when I input a value to make the statement true.

Comment: I think you just want if not b instead of if b == 44993

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Pro tip: Try to use more descriptive variable names.  If you use (for example) `def compute_xp(extra_xp, battle_won):`, then the error becomes much more obvious: `if battle_won == 44993:` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @0x5453 unless your're one of those solo badasses that don't care, right? Or is that like a cowboy builder? Hmmm...

Answer (score 2):

In the original code example, `if b == 44993:` compares the parameter `b` to `44993`.
Since `b` is expected to be a boolean, this comparison will always return `false`.

Here is my solution:

```
def compute_xp(i, b):
  if b:
      return 44993 + i
  else:
      return 44993
```

`if b:` checks the boolean value of `b`, so if `b` is `true`, then `return 44993 + i` will be executed. If `b` is `false`, then `return 44993` will be executed.

Comment: please try to make your answer more useful to OP by explaining what the difference is between his and your code and why it matters. Code only answers are not really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you comparing the boolean var with the number? Try:

```
def compute_xp(i, b):
    if b:
        return 44993 + i
    else:
        return 44993
```

or more shortly:

```
def compute_xp(i, b):
    return 44993 + i if b else 44993
```

Comment: "Why are you doing this or that" is not a productive way to begin your answer. Can you please go into further detail as to what the OP did incorrectly and why you changed the code in the way you did?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-think this.

Here is what I would do:

```
def compute_xp(int_value, bool_value):
    if b == True:
        #If the battle is won run this code block
        #return 44993, int_value (this would return two seperate things," (44993, int_value) ")
        return 44993 + i
    else:
        #If the battle is lost, run this code
        return 44993
```

The reason you code does not work, is because you are trying to interpret a Boolean value as an integer, `if b == 44993` which of course, will always be false, because neither `True` nor `False` are `== 44993`.

So what my code does, is check the value of the boolean explicitly, so only in the event that `b == True` will it `return 44993 + i`

I added an extra line to the code in the form of a comment. `return 44993 + i` doesn't seem like a useful thing to return. Returning `44993, i` would return a tuple, index 0 would be an integer and index 1 would be your int_value.

Answer (score 0):

try this. Remember a boolean can only have one of two values true or false so it can never be set equal to a number.

```
def compute_xp(x,y):
    if y == True:
        return (x + 44993)
    else:
        return 44993
```